# Simple 2 way encryption for image

Tags: encryption

In my browser based application,we have to encrypte the image in the server side,and then decrypte it in the client using flash or other language,then display it.

First, I try to use the "System.Security.Cryptography" int .net2 to do the encrypte,but I am afraid in the client side the image can not be decrpyted using flash or others.

SO I wonder if there is some solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you deliver it via a Secure Socket Layer?(HTTPS) Just force it for all the site if you want.

Comment: case our boss does not trust the https,he just think encrypte the image is safe. So We must make sure that the image transferred in the network must be encrypted.

Comment: That is what HTTPS is for. How would you transfer the decoder in the first place? I mean you pass the "flash" program via HTTP, if someone can tamper with it you are screwed.

Comment: yes,usiong the hidden flash in the page to decode the image and show them in the page. Now,just assume the flash is safe enougth.

Comment: How is it delivered? HTTPS or HTTP?

Comment: the encrypted image are delivered by http.

Comment: the decrypter is the flash,that's why use it in the page,since we do not think the js can inner the browser can used to decrypt the image.